# MySQL: How to ensure thread safety and avoid duplicate key errors, when Primary Key is generated in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, thread-safety

I have a table in which the primary key is a 20 character VARCHAR field that gets generated in PHP before getting inserted into the table. The key generation logic uses grouping and sequencing mechanism as given below.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(prod_code, 15) AS prod_num
FROM
    items
  , products
WHERE
    items.cat_type    = $category
    AND items.sub_grp = $sub_grp
    AND items.prod_id = products.prod_id
ORDER BY
    prod_num DESC LIMIT 1
```

The prod_num thus got is incremented in PHP and prefixed with a product code to create a unique primary key. However multiple users can do the transaction concurrently for same category and sub_group leading to same keys generated for those users. This may lead to duplicate key error, as its a unique primary key. What is the best way to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "Smart IDs".

Smart IDs were all the rage in the 1980s, and went out of fashion for several reasons:

- The only requirement of a PK is that is has to be unique. A PK doesn't need to have a format, or to be sexy or good looking. Their specific sequence, case, or composition is not relevant and actually counter-productive.
- They are not relational. Parts of the ID could establish a relationship with other tables and that can cause a lot of issues. This goes against Normal Forms defined in database design.

Now, if you still need a Smart ID, then create a secondary column (that can also be unique) and then populate it after the row is created. If you are facing thread safety issues, you can run a single deferred process that will assign nice looking values after a few minutes. Alternatively, you can implement a queue, that can resolve this is seconds.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the design I have is from the 80's!!! The PK is a product tag/id and helps the staff to identify its category by looking at the tag for appropriate cataloging or shelving. This also goes into the barcode for scanning. This is unique and even if I have it as a secondary column that has to be unique and will end up with "Duplicate value for unique column" error. So the problem remains unless I implement a queue.

Comment: @Die-Bugger When inserting a new row, the secondary column is typically populated with a null (can be other value but null is common) that should be interpreted as "pending". Then the deferred process, or a priority queue (typically a priority queue), or something else will populate the value ensuring it's unique. The value remains as pending only for a few minutes/hours.

Comment: Though I can use multiple design cues to implement the pending logic with deferred process or a queue, during that period those products will be unavailable till the product code gets updated. I should also ensure that only those products that are not in pending state alone to be picked up for consumption by downstream systems. Overall, I agree with your second point on Smart IDs. Have to check with business and DBA together to decide the design approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Die-Bugger Just a note. In one case I remember around 10 years ago, we had a dedicated server -- the locking server -- which one and only purpose was to provide unique IDs for a cluster of other server in real time. The downside of this solution was that when the locking server went down (and it did quite a bit at some point) the rest of the servers would also crash. Maybe a "short-circuit" pattern could help in these cases.

Comment: We fixed this by moving the key generation logic to the DB as a trigger. So far so good. No locking or duplicate key issues. In future the PK will be a AI column and the product code will become a unique key column.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with "The Impaler".

But if you decide to proceed that way: to handle your concurrency issue could be through a retry-mechanism.
This is similar to how deadlocks are typically handled.

If the insertion fails because of violation of the unique primary key, just try again in PHP with a new key.
Your framework might have retry functions already. Otherwise it's easy to implement yourself.

Comment: Retry is a nice option and have implemented it before.